# Which is the better way (for performance) to determine the exception type?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have overridden `OnException` from `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.

```
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {

        base.OnException(context);
    }
```

This is called when an error is thrown and passes through the exception as an argument :- `context.Exception`

Which is the best way for performance to determine the type of error:

**1). Throw and Catch**

```
    //create a new response that will be sent to the API consumer
    var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
    //throw the error that came through to catch it specifically
    try {
        throw context.Exception;
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
```

**2). Get Type**

```
        //create a new response that will be sent to the API consumer
        var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();

        //switch on the exception type
        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)) {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
        else if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(Exception)) {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
```

**3).** Some other way?

Comment: I would avoid the first way. Throwing existing exceptions around only to get their types does not strike me as the best solution, both performance and maintainability-wise.

Comment: and if you're going the second way, then only evaluate `context.Exception.GetType()` once and cache it

Comment: Another option is using the `is` operator.  That would be useful if you wanted to know if the exceptions also inherited from a specific type, thus being more like throwing and catching.  As it stands your second method's second if will only be true if the type of the exception is `Exception` whereas the first method catches all other exceptions with the second catch.

Comment: When an exception is thrown it includes *stack tracing* which is *slow*, that's why performance is not an option in any ways.

Comment: You can still make the best of a bad situation though...

Comment: Those two are not equivalent. Consider what would happen in each with an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect (though haven't confirmed) that first method is going to clobber stack trace data, or in some other way(s) modify the exception itself and lose the original information.  Even if by coincidence it doesn't do this, it's still not great for performance and semantic reasons.  `throw`ing is expensive, the source of the exception becomes slightly harder to determine when debugging, and it breaks the standard rule of never using exceptions for logic flow.

The *structure* of the second approach is better, but its implementation can be improved.  Something like this:

```
var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();

if (context.Exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException) {
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
}
else {
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

**Update:** The comments are correct, a runtime check on any other exception would succeed with the `Exception` type so the check is unnecessary.  Just check for the specific exception types, then default to anything else.

Comment: I messed up translating my code over, 'is Exception' is the default case.

Comment: That second if should handle all cases assuming that `context.Exception` is not null.

Comment: This is spot on though, and what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: The `else if` should actually be just an `else` - `context.Exception` *is* an exception, so the check is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to achieve, but I definitely would not throw and catch the exception just to determine the type.  In addition to your 2nd method you might also want to consider using the `is` operator.  That will work more like throwing and catching since it checks if the object can be cast to the type whereas `GetType` will get the exact type of the exception.

```
var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
if (context.Exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException) 
{
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
}
else if (context.Exception is IOException) 
{
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

In the example above the first if is for only `FileNotFoundException` and the second is for any other exception that is or inherits from `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

Three.

Throwing the exception to catch it means that a whole new exception object is created, so that is a lot more work than is needed.

The second method is better, but it can be improved on.

You can use the `is` operator to check the type of an object:

```
if (context.Exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException)) {
  response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
} else if (context.Exception is Exception) {
  response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

You can get the name of the class and use in a switch:

```
switch (context.Exception.GetType().FullName) {
  case "System.IO.FileNotFoundException":
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    break;
  case "Exception":
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    break;
}
```

Note that there is a difference in what different methods match. The `is` operator will also include base types (just as `catch(Exception)`), so `context.Exception is Exception` will be true for all exception. The switch will only do an exact match, just as `context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(Exception)`.